# Merge Sort With Linked List

Tags: java, merge, linked-list, mergesort

I am trying to create a program for my computer science class that takes a linked list and sorts it via the merge sort algorithm. I'm having difficulty with taking the linked list and recursively splitting the nodes by finding the middle node. I have three classes, one for my node, my list, and for the merge sort class.

```
static Mynode h;
static Mylist list = new Mylist();

public static void Sort(String[] list){
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    /*
    node sort(node h);
    node l2 = split(h);
    */
    list.insert("cat");
    list.insert("ok");
            list.insert("ok");

    list.printdata();
    split(list);
}

public void sort(){
    String head;
}
public static void merge(Mylist list, int right, int left){

}
public static void split(Mylist list){
    Mynode tempFast = h;
    Mynode tempslow = h;        
    Iterator iterator = tempFast.iterator();
    Iterator iterator = tempslow.iterator();

        while(tempslow.getNext()!=null && tempslow.getNext()!=null){
            tempFast.getNext();
            tempFast.getNext();
            tempslow.getNext();
        }
}

public Merge(String data){
    /*
    this.data = data; 
    */
}

/*
public Node msort(String r){

}
    /*
    node l2 = split(h);
    h = msort(h);
    l2 = msort(l2);
    return merge(h, l2);
    */
}

// input: java myms < word3
// output: Unsorted: cow, zebra, ant || Sorted: ant, cat, zebra

static Mynode h;
public Mylist(){
    this.h = null;
}

public void insert(String s) {
//method for node insertion
   this.h = new Mynode(s, this.h);
}
public boolean contains(String s){
//method for identifying contains specific data
    Mynode temp = this.h;
    while(temp !=null){
    //while the node contains a value
        if(s.equals(temp.getData())){
        //if the node contains the specified data, return true
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp.getNext();
        //set the node reference to the next value
    }
    return false;
}
public void printdata(){
    Mynode temp = this.h;
    while(temp !=null){
        System.out.println(temp.getData());
        //print the current node, then increment the temp node one over
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
}
public void deletion (String s){
//method for deletion
    Mynode temp = this.h;
    Mynode previous = null;
    if (temp != null && temp.getData().equals(s)) {
    //when node contains data and the specified data matched the node in the linked list 
        this.h = temp.getNext();
        //node reference is set to the next value
        return; 
    } 
    while (temp != null && !(temp.getData().equals(s))) { 
    //retrieve node reference for next value
        previous = temp; 
        temp = temp.getNext(); 
        //set node to the next value
    } 
    if(temp ==null) {
        return;
    }
    previous.setNext((temp.getNext())); 

}
public Iterator iterator() {
    return new Myiter(this.h);
}
private class Myiter implements Iterator {

    private Mynode temp;

    public Myiter(Mynode temp) {
        this.temp = h;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
    //checks if there is an element next in the list
        return this.temp != null;
    }
    public Object next() {
    //gets the next element in the list
        Object returndata = this.temp.getData();
        temp = temp.getNext();
        return  returndata;
    }
    public void remove() {
    //not implemented
    }
}
}

public class Mynode {
private String data;
private Mynode next;
public Mynode (String d, Mynode n){
    this.data = d;
    this.next =n;
}
public String getData(){
    return this.data;
}
public void setNext(Mynode n){
    this.next = n;
}
public Mynode getNext(){
    return this.next;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to debug if we are given the Mynode class as well.

From the information that we are given right now, it seems like the split method will be an infinite look.

The getNext method in a LinkedList should not change anything in the current object, it should just be a getter for the next node in the list. Because you are calling getNext but not storing the Mynode that is returned in any way, the getNext method will return the same node because the "tempFast" and "tempSlow" are never referencing the next Mynode in the list.

Instead of the code here:

```
    while(tempslow.getNext()!=null && tempslow.getNext()!=null){
        tempFast.getNext();
        tempFast.getNext();
        tempslow.getNext();
    }
```

I would recommend setting the tempFast and tempSlow variables to the next node in the list, like so:

```
    while(tempslow.getNext()!=null && tempslow.getNext()!=null){
        tempFast = tempFast.getNext();
        if(tempFast != null){
            tempFast = tempFast.getNext();
        }
        tempSlow = tempslow.getNext();
    }
```

Comment: just posted the mynode class, how would i use the iterator class to proceed through my linked list i created?